# Does Numba use GPU by default?

Tags: python, numba

Right now, I'm working on my diploma and as I use Numba I'd like to fully understand it.
As written on docs, it translates functions to machine codes, and since I didn't saw anything about GPU I'm curious, why my GPU is being so active while executing code:

```
def meanHdist(fig1, fig2):
    n1 = fig1.shape[0]
    n2 = fig2.shape[0]
    dist_matrix = np.zeros((n1, n2))
    min1 = np.full(n1, np.inf)
    min2 = np.full(n2, np.inf)
    for i in range(n1):
        for j in range(n2):
            dist_matrix[i, j] = np.sqrt((fig1[i, 0] - fig2[j, 0])**2 + (fig1[i, 1] - fig2[j, 1])**2)
            min1[i] = np.minimum(min1[i], dist_matrix[i, j])
            min2[j] = np.minimum(min2[j], dist_matrix[i, j])
    d1 = np.mean(min1)
    d2 = np.mean(min2)
    h_dist = np.maximum(d1, d2)
    return h_dist
```

Does it execute it on GPU after translating in addition or what happens?

P.S. Please give as large answer as possible, every extra symbol in paper is worth of gold :)

Comment: By default the CUDA driver selects the fastest GPU as the device 0, which is the default device used by Numba.

Comment: By default and unless you precise it, Numba should not use GPUs. One simple reason is that using GPUs are not always faster and moving data from the host to GPUs device is quite expensive (with a high latency hard to hide for small datasets). What makes you think it does? Can you provide the code suspected to use the GPU?

Comment: Added code to the question